# How can I view I/O stats of a partitioned table at the partition level

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have partitioned my table by a date column into 10 partitions and would like to see how EACH partition is getting used (I/O stats, etc.).  I would hope this would give some insight into how the existing queries are using individual partitions, if at all, so that I might optimize the queries.  Is there a way of determining the I/O stats AT THE PARTITION LEVEL?

Comment: was your question addressed?. If so,  can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few approaches:

1. It is possible via: [sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-io-virtual-file-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

But it will work only in case if every partition resides in own filegroup

2. Another way is [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

This DMV can provide data structure usage stats per object/index/partition:

```
sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats (    
    { database_id | NULL | 0 | DEFAULT }    
  , { object_id | NULL | 0 | DEFAULT }    
  , { index_id | 0 | NULL | -1 | DEFAULT }    
  , { partition_number | NULL | 0 | DEFAULT }    
)
```

Comment: Since I did not separate the partitions onto filegroups, looking at the index op stats provided the most info.